# Are "compared to" and "with respect to" interchangeable?

Tags: comparatives

For example:

*The results showed higher stability for the first enzyme **compared to** the second one.*

Would this sentence have the same meaning if I changed **compared to** with **with respect to**?

Comment: They are not that close. *A compared to B* considers both on some scale. *A with respect to B* judges A on a certain aspect part of B, but not weighing one against the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, these do not mean the same thing. "Compared to" draws a direct comparison between one object and another. The proper phrase in the example sentence is "compared to" - the first enzyme has a higher stability than the second one, so it is a direct comparison.

"With respect to" is a synonym for "regarding" or "in the context of". One could say that an enzyme has "high stability with respect to temperature and time", for example, indicating in what context the stability is being discussed. The phrase is not used to draw a comparison between objects, but instead further clarify or describe particular aspects of one object.